# How to set HtmlNode.ElementsFlags per instance instead of global context in HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing, html-agility-pack, dom

I need to set different sets of HtmlNode.ElementsFlags to several instances of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument. For example, I might have one HtmlDocument parsing with 'a' tags as HtmlElementFlag.Empty, and another instance of HtmlDocument parsing 'a' tags as HtmlElementFlag.Closed.

So far the only way I can change these flags is through a global context dictionary that is in HtmlNode.ElementsFlags. I have tested and it will change the flags even if I am running on different threads.

The question would be if I am missing an easy way to pass the flags in an instance context? If not, is there an easy way to modify HAP to get it working?

Thanks